# CPU usage of my app is high when switching to airplane mode

Tags: android, performance

Actually I have the problem that the cpu usage of my app is getting high when the user goes into the airplane mode. I can see that is constantly uses 40 % of the cpu. I checked already my services and added broadcastreceivers which are listing to BLUETOOTH.STATE_CHANGE broadcast so that the services will be stopped. In the DDMS I can see that the Garbage Collector is massivly working while the airplane is on.

Any idea what the reason for this can be? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you please check for infinite loops? You open airplane mode and debug device,since data transfer is not allowed in airplane mode. An exception may be causing it to fall into infinite loop

Comment: There is no infinite loop. I can see a lot of Garbarge Collection is done with the message GC_FOR_ALLOC freed